# Changing delimiter of the uniq command

Tags: uniq

I'd like the output of the uniq command to be comma separated, so that instead of:

```
     30 hello
     31 world
     36 hey_there
    142 i_am_bigest
```

I'll get:

```
30,hello
31,world
36,hey_there
142,i_am_biggest
```

My input has no spaces, but just using `sed` or `tr` can be a problem since the number of leading spaces varies according to the number of decimal digits in the count.

Comment: This Q. specifically looks like changing the output of `... | sort -rn | uniq -c`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pipe the output to

```
sed -e 's/^ *//;s/ /,/'
```

This first removes the leading spaces (`^ *`) then replaces the first space with a comma.

Answer (score 4):

`man uniq` (at least on Mac OS X, aka BSD) does not give any way to handle that.  Your best bet is probably `sed`:

```
... |
uniq -c |
sed 's/^ *\([0-9][0-9]*\) /\1,/'
```

The output from `uniq -c` consists of some blanks, a number, a blank, and the input string.

The basic idea is that the `sed` script looks for an arbitrary number of blanks, a number and a blank, and replace it by the number and a comma.  Looking at the POSIX specification for [`uniq`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html), the output is not supposed to have leading blanks (the `printf()` format should be `"%d %s"`), but leading blanks are normal in practice (for small enough repeat counts; on Mac OS X, the output `printf()` format is effectively `"%5d %s"`).

Answer (score 1):

pipe the output to :

```
perl -lane '{print join ",", @F}'
```

Comment: As with the `awk`-based solution, this does not work well when the input lines have multiple fields according to Perl.  For example, with sorted input consisting of 4 lines containing `aaa aaa aaa aaa` and 5 lines containing `aba aba aba aba`, the ouptut from your script (after `sort` and `uniq -c`) is two lines: `4,aaa,aaa,aaa,aaa` and `5,aba,aba,aba,aba`; note the extra (and unwanted) commas.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using `printf` works:

   ```
   xargs -L 1 printf '%s,%s\n' < file
   ```
2. Using `bash`:

   ```
   printf '%s,%s\n' $(<file)
   ```
3. In a *POSIX* shell this would also work:

   ```
   printf '%s,%s\n' $( ...various commands... | uniq -c )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Using @nneonneo's answer, I wrote this function and added it to my .bashrc:

```
uniqc(){
    uniq -c |sed -e 's/^ *//;s/ /,/' 
}
```

Usage, instead of `doSomething | uniq -c`, do:

```
doSomething | uniqc
```